# Selecting column label as row value in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df_input = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])
```

For all the rows, only one column has non zero entry. Accordingly, the output dataframe I am expecting is as follows:-

```
df_output=pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C','D','E'],columns=['Alphabet'])
```

The alphabet column should have the column name of non zero value. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` along `axis=1`:

```
df_input.ne(0).idxmax(1).to_frame('Alphabet')
```

---

```
  Alphabet
0        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
4        E
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dot product after getting a boolean df checking for not equals 0.

If there are chances of multiple columns having a non zero value for a row and you want to get the first:

```
df_input.ne(0).dot(df_input.columns+',').str.split(",").str[0].to_frame('Alphabet')
```

If there will be only 1 column with a non zero value always , then we can use `rstrip` like @Shubham mentioned in their coments.

```
df_input.ne(0).dot(df_input.columns+',').str.rstrip(',').to_frame('Alphabet')
```

---

```
  Alphabet
0        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
4        E
```